# How do I update the time in oracle sql?

Tags: oracle

I need a query to update a time in an appointment date by keeping the date but changing the time.
For example

10-Feb-2016 09:00:00
and i  want to change it to  10-Feb-2016 10:00:00.

```
Update Appointment
set vdate = '10:00:00'
where vdate= '10-Feb-2016'
```

I get the "0 row has been updated'. Not sure if i'm missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell what is type of `vdate` ?

Comment: The type is a Date.

Comment: If its `Date` only then you can not update time there, you must have to use `datetime`

Comment: @BharatPatidar: Auxion uses Oracle and `DATE` does have a time there

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`trunc()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm#SQLRF06151) which sets the time part of a `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) to  `00:00:00`, then add the 10 hours to it:

```
Update Appointment
   set vdate = trunc(vdate) + interval '10' hour
where trunc(vdate) = DATE '2016-02-10'
```

This would change **all** rows that have a date `2016-02-10`. If you only want to do that for those that are at 09:00 (ignoring the minutes and seconds) then just add one hour to those rows

```
Update Appointment
   set vdate = trunc(vdate) + interval '1' hour
where trunc(vdate, 'hh24') = timestamp '2016-02-10 09:00:00'
```

`trunc(vdate, 'hh24')` will set the minutes and seconds of the `date` value to `00:00`, so that the comparison with `2016-02-10 09:00:00` works properly.

---

Unrelated, but: do **not** rely on implicit data type conversion. `'10-Feb-2016'` is a string value, not a DATE literal. To specify a date either use an ANSI DATE literal (as I have done in the above statement) or use the [`to_date()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132) function **with** a format mask to convert a string literal to a proper date value.

Your statement is subject to the evil implicit data type conversion and will fail if the SQL client running the statement uses a different NLS setting (it will fail on my computer for example)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
UPDATE MyTable
 SET MyDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 4, CAST(CAST(MyDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

or

```
UPDATE MyTable 
 SET MyDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 4, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(MyDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
```

Comment: There is no data type `datetime` in Oracle. Or a function `dateadd`

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is add an hour to a date, then you can do:

```
Update Appointment
set    vdate = vdate + 1/24
where  vdate = to_date('10/02/2016 09:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi');
```

since in Oracle, date differences are measured in number of days, and an hour is 1/24th of a day.

If what you want to do is specify an exact time (e.g. to 10:25:48), then you could do the following instead:

```
Update Appointment
set    vdate = trunc(vdate) + 10/24 + 25/(24*60) + 48/(24*60*60)
where  vdate = to_date('10/02/2016 09:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi');
```

Bear in mind that these updates will update all rows that have a date of 10th Feb 2016 at 9am. You'd need to change your query's where clause if you wanted to specify a more specific row or set of rows.